# How does SQL and SQL-MR query works internally in Teradata aster?

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, teradata

I'm currently exploring Tera data Aster(Aster express 6). I've gone through documentation and blogs but no where it is explained how querying works.
since it is distributed how they sql and sql-mr fetches data, do they generate map reduce jobs internally ?

for example customer table has 10 records which are distributed by hash(customer id) and say they're 3 workers(nothing but nodes in asterdata), data split among them as 3 records each on two nodes and 4 on one node.

In SQL 
 the simple select * from customers; will work in this case?

but in aster data this query works.

How does it fetches records from 3 nodes? if normal sql query can fecth records then why we need MapReduce, we can use mutliple sub queries to accomplish are tasks?

If data is distributed among multiple machines then mapreduce is the only way to process data?

It'll really help me if someone explains this!

Pradi

Comment: The subject of parallel and distributed databases seems too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

www.teradata.com/white-paper/Using-SQL-MapReduce-for-Advanced-Analytical-Queries/ is a white paper sponsored by Teradata which explains their rationale for incorporating MapReduce alongside SQL, and should be a good starting pointing for improving understanding.